Deploy contract, but address is still undefined
I'm using geth to learning the web3. The version is as follows:
 go：v1.22.1
 nodejs：v21.7.1
 npm：v10.5.0
 solidity：v0.8.25
 geth：v1.13.14


I run the geth in dev mode which means:
  1. This mode is only intended for fast, iterative development without assumptions on
     security or persistence.
  2. The database is created in memory unless specified otherwise. Therefore, shutting down
     your computer or losing power will wipe your entire block data and chain state for
     your dev environment.
  3. A random, pre-allocated developer account will be available and unlocked as
     eth.coinbase, which can be used for testing. The random dev account is temporary,
     stored on a ramdisk, and will be lost if your machine is restarted.
  4. Mining is enabled by default. However, the client will only seal blocks if transactions
     are pending in the mempool. The miner's minimum accepted gas price is 1.
  5. Networking is disabled; there is no listen-address, the maximum number of peers is set
     to 0, and discovery is disabled.


I want to deploy a simple contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract Hello {
  string greeting;

  constructor(string memory _greeting) {
    greeting = _greeting;
  }

  function say() public view returns (string memory) {
    return greeting;
  }
}


I also write pre.js, the abi and the bytecode are generated from the solc:
var abi = [
  {
    inputs: [{ internalType: "string", name: "_greeting", type: "string" }],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "constructor",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "say",
    outputs: [{ internalType: "string", name: "", type: "string" }],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

var bytecode =
  "...";

var HelloContract = eth.contract(abi);

var tx = { from: eth.accounts[0], data: bytecode, gas: "1000000" };

var helloInstance = HelloContract.new(tx);


Then I run the command to start geth with dev mode:
geth -datadir testNet -dev console --preload "./pre.js"


The info is here:
INFO [04-08|19:31:18.135] Submitted contract creation              hash=0x66c7fe5e121e17427682a5af4ee1b61600194bf166b360edaed192f55e0bb44d from=0x728515076e3D5b4950cE5cDb77a612874f24B1CA nonce=20 contract=0x3DCB2CbC4DaE4244e9010a90D0d145bdE2D7B06a value=0
INFO [04-08|19:31:18.137] Starting work on payload                 id=0x02755c773073ef4e
INFO [04-08|19:31:18.137] Updated payload                          id=0x02755c773073ef4e number=33 hash=0846eb..3d86e9 txs=1 withdrawals=0 gas=79434 fees=7.9434e-14 root=53527d..8574da elapsed="662.556µs"
INFO [04-08|19:31:18.138] Stopping work on payload                 id=0x02755c773073ef4e reason=delivery
INFO [04-08|19:31:18.140] Imported new potential chain segment     number=33 hash=0846eb..3d86e9 blocks=1 txs=1 mgas=0.079 elapsed=1.873ms     mgasps=42.407 snapdiffs=3.27KiB triedirty=1.19KiB
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.13.14-stable-2bd6bd01/linux-amd64/go1.22.0
coinbase: 0x728515076e3d5b4950ce5cdb77a612874f24b1ca
at block: 32 (Mon Apr 08 2024 19:24:15 GMT+0800 (CST))
 datadir: /home/gentle/projects/homeworks/blockchain/eth00/testNet
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 dev:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

To exit, press ctrl-d or type exit
> INFO [04-08|19:31:18.141] Chain head was updated                   number=33 hash=0846eb..3d86e9 root=53527d..8574da elapsed=1.429815ms

means the contract info was deployed into the chain
however when I type the helloInstance
I got:
{
  abi: [{
      inputs: [{...}],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "constructor"
  }, {
      inputs: [],
      name: "say",
      outputs: [{...}],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }],
  address: undefined,
  transactionHash: "0x66c7fe5e121e17427682a5af4ee1b61600194bf166b360edaed192f55e0bb44d"
}


the address is still undefined and means I can't invoke the contract
I'll be appreciated if someone can solve this
